# In a Mern Stack project where should I store the images?

Tags: mern

In a MERN stack project in which folder should I place the images such as logo image. I tried storing it in the image folder under src folder of app folder but it remains untracked. What is the correct approach of storing images such as logo image?

Answer (score 1):

You can store all your assets in assets folder in your main folder and then access anything as /assets/anything.png